# CoreData find indexPath of entry

Tags: string, swift, core-data, xcode6, nsindexpath

I have an CoreData model with the entity `Person` and an attribute called `name`. I store 4 strings into `name` (`Pete`, `Paul`, `Dan` and `Jo`). Now I'd like to find out which indexPath `Paul` has. How can I do this?

My CoreData model:
[image]

Comment: Core Data objects don't have index paths. An index path can (for example) describe the position of a row in a table view. Can you clarify what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm displaying the list of the names (Pete, Paul, Dan and Jo) in an UITableView and like to find out the indexPath for the name Paul. So the indexPath of the cell which displays the name Paul.

Comment: @MartinR Do you understand what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Do you have 4 `Person` objects each with a `name`, or do you have a `Person` object with a `name` string property that lists names in brackets separated by commas?

Comment: Do you got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

To display Core Data entities in a table view, you should use a `NSFetchedResultsController`. One requirement is that the entities you fetch must be sorted, so the index path is unequivocal.

To find the index path of a `Person` object in your fetched results controller driven table view, use

```
let indexPath = self.fetchedResultsController.indexPathForObject(person)!
```

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your answer! Yes, I use `NSFetchedResultsController`. I updated my question with my core data model. The names (`Pete`, `Paul`, `Dan` and `Jo`) are stored in `name`. Now I want to find out the indexPath of the cell in which `Paul` is displayed.

Comment: Do you got a solution?